# Find if these sequences converge and if so compute the limit

Tags: analysis

I'm stuck with these two sequences and just do not know how to solve them. 
Decide if these sequences converge (where n is an element of the natural numbers without 0)and calculate if so the limit.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}&\bullet\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\\{}\\&\bullet \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n+k}}\ge\frac n{\sqrt{n+n}}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Ahh I see so the first one would converge via the sandwich-theorem and the second one diverges?

Comment: @AjaxEdm Indeed so. Try to come up with a more or less formal argument to write down.

Comment: Perfect ;) Thank's alot

Answer (score 1):

Try some comparison : each term of $c_n$ verifies
$$\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}=\frac{1}{n}$$
so 
$$\frac{n}{n+1}\le c_n\le \frac{n}{n}$$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n=1$.

You can certainly find a relevant double inequality for each term of $e_n$. Hint : $\lim_{n\to\infty}e_n=+\infty$ :-)